# How to make a Machine-In-The-Middle with a dual NIC PC in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, tap

I would like to use a Linux PC fitted with two network interface cards as a transparent bridge in order to capture (with wireshark or equivalent) all the traffic in both directions between my router/gateway and my main host (a Windows PC).
The following figure illustrates what i'm talking about, my Linux PC will be inserted as a spy or MITM in the link:

[image: Machine in the middle]

Source: [wireshark.org](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=Capture-switch-mitm-2NIC-ws.png)

I know that using a managed switch with port mirroring is the most common solution for that but i'd prefer to try setting up this one in order to learn. I have already installed CentOS 7 on the spy PC and can I see my two NICs with an `ip a` command: `eno1` and `enp1s0`. I would appreciate some help for the next steps please, since i'm not so familiar with Linux bridges (if bridging is the solution, you will tell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember building something like that x years ago using the bridge utilities. On Debian/Ubuntu the package "bridge-utils" is your friend. Install with:

```
apt install bridge-utils
```

and look at the man page to see how to configure and use it:

```
man bridge-utils-interfaces
man brctl
```

In your CentOS7 environment you can install it with yum:

```
yum install bridge-utils
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to mention that I was in CentOS 7.9, in which bridge-utils has been deprecated. Apart from that, do you suggest bridging eno1 and enp1s0 together, and that's it ? But what about capturing the traffic ?

Comment: The iproute2 package should have taken over the functionality of bridge-utils and does contain a 'bridge' utility, (see 'sudo bridge --help'). Second, 'ip link' does support bridge type interfaces according to it's man page ('man ip link'). I don't know your local interface names, but that sounds about right. Capturing you can do with tcpdump or wireshark.

Comment: @JdeHann Ok I tried and it works! Let's call eth1 and eth2 the names of the Ethernet interfaces used to sniff (to be changed according to the particular PC) :
`ip link add name br0 type bridge`
`ip link set br0 up`
`ip link set eth1 master br0`
`ip link set eth2 master br0`
Then I could sniff all packets with a:
`tcpdump -i eth1`
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Can you mark my answer up and as best with the up-arrow?

Comment: @JdeHann, sure, done for the check. For the vote, as soon as I get 15 reputation points, i'm nearly there! :-)